# Lossless video output is overbrighted

Tags: video, color, encoding

I am rendering a video with overlayed PNG sequence (clouds with alpha channel).

Output settings are **mp4, h.264 (Lossless)**. But final video is overbrighted, however if I change **h.264** to **PNG codec**, it gives original result.

See how **PNG codec** preserves clouds details, while **h.264** is full white:
[image]

Problem exists only with PNG sequence, original footage doesn't suffer from overbrightening.

I don't know what to do, stick with PNG codec - but wouldn't be there any compatibility problems with DVD players and other stuff